# Qt - how to use QDir::entryList() to filter both files with specific file types and directories at the same time

Tags: qt, qt5

Is that possible to retrieve file names with specific file types and directory names at the same time by using `QDir::entryList()`?

I have had the flag `QDir::Dirs` in my code. But since I added `<< "*.mp4"`, it ignored the folders.

```
void Hierarchy::setItems(const QString& path, int level)
{
    QDir source(path);
    if (!source.exists())
        return;

    QStringList folders = source.entryList(QStringList() << "*.mp4", 
            QDir::Files | QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot | QDir::Dirs);

    for (int i = 0; i < folders.size(); ++i) {
        qDebug() << "Level " << i << " " << folders[i];
        setItems(path + "/" + folders[i] + "/", level++);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create two lists: one for the folders and another for the files:

```
void setItems(QString const& path, int level)
{
    QDir const source(path);
    if (!source.exists())
        return;

    QStringList const files = source.entryList(QStringList() << "*.mp4", QDir::Files);
    QStringList const folders = source.entryList(QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot | QDir::Dirs);

    QStringList const all = folders + files;

    for (QString const& name: all)
    {
        QString const fullPathName = path + QDir::separator() + name;
        if (QFileInfo(fullPathName).isDir())
        {
            setItems(fullPathName, level++);
            continue;
        }
        qDebug() << "Level " << level << " " << fullPathName;
    }
}
```